# Calling a function from a class method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a function from a class method. How do I go about setting this function up?

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {}
  animal() {
    // I tried something like this but it didn't work.
    var addAnimal = function () {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}

var myclass = new MyClass();
```

Ultimately, my goal is to be able to do this: `myclass.animal.addAnimal();`

Comment: addAnimal is a var, you're not assigning  it to the function. Do this.addAnimal = function(){}

Comment: but then `myclass.animal.addAnimal();` would still be undefined @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is more look like `Function Objects` rather than class function ....

```js
var MyClass = {
  animal : {
    // I tried something like this but it didn't work.
    addAnimal : function () {
      return 'Dog';
    }
  }
};
console.log(MyClass.animal.addAnimal());
```